# Error when delete 2d array

Tags: c++

I'm not good at English (I'm Vietnamese, so that there may be some Grammatical Errors in my question).

Today, I'm doing my coding exercise, I detect an error when I delete a 2d array. After that, I write a simple code to test and it have the same error! here is my test code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int main()
{

     int **test;
     int i;
     test= new*[3];
     for(i=0;i<3;i++)
     {
             test[i]=new int[1];
             test[0][i]=0;
     }

     for(i=0;i<3;i++)
             delete[] test[i];
     delete[] test;

     return 0;
}
```

-when I debug my code,I detect error occurs at line "delete[] test[i];". A window appears, and tells me that:

- Windows has triggered a breakpoint in test.exe
- This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in test.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
- This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while test.exe has focus.
- The output window may have more diagnostic information.

-and in the output window:

"HEAP[test.exe] Heap block at X modified at Y past requested size of 28"

Note:

- if I don't use delete, the error doesn't occur.
- the error only occurs when i=0.
- if I allocate a 2d array with only 1 element, there is no error occur (delete[] test[0]; //run normaly)

Any idea what exact the problem is?
Thank you.

Comment: `test [0][i]` where test [0] is only one int long is undefined behaviour. Erroring like that is the nicest thing your program could do.

Comment: is this line `test= new*[3];` wrong ? , `test[0][i]=0;` there is a problem here (you create new arrays of one element so you can use it like `test[i][0]=0;` not `test[0][i]=0;` )

Comment: I see the problem, thanks all! I think I must review 2d array :D

Comment: `test= new*[3];` is a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test[0][i]=0;` got the indices the wrong way around - it should be `test[i][0]=0;` to be consistent with the line before, `test[i]`.

All your other reasoning is fine.